# UICollectionView have prototyp cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView and i would to have at first in the view Prototyp cells because it´s looks good. So i have nothing found so i ask this Question here. They cell are only for the first than it´s save normal images in it. The Prototyp Cells must be on the whole view so it must be 15 or 20 Prototyp cells.  In the Picture you can see it what i am mean. 
 So how i can make that?

Have somebody a idea how i can make that ? 
Thanks for your Help.

[UICollectionView with gray prototype cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYQOg.jpg)

Comment: its not clear what you are asking for.  Can you try clarify so we can help?

Comment: In the Picture there is a UICollectionView there are cells but the cells are not filled with data so it´s a gray Prototyp cell and when the user makes a foto the cell filled with a image. So i would have the Prototyp cell (ca.10) in the UICollectionView, looks better as a gray background screen. I hope it´s declared. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Hey, come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Comment: Have you an idea how i can make that??